# MySQL and PHP - Filtering by multiple criteria in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a standard code to search by column and am now trying to add the option of searching multiple criteria in one column.
Currently I can search by one criteria, so if the user selects location QLD it will display all QLD entries, what changes do i need to make to enable the user to search both for location QLD and NSW?

I have updated the  element to be multiple, but am not sure how to adjust the PHP and MySQL to process multiple criteria.

Can someone help?

Thanks,
sbgmedia

```
<?php
$condition  =   '';
if(isset($_REQUEST['Location']) and $_REQUEST['Location']!=""){
    $condition  .=  ' AND Location LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['Location'].'%" ';
}

$userData   =   $db->getAllRecords('candidates','*',$condition,'ORDER BY id ASC');
?>
```

```html
<select name="Location[]" id="Location" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['Location'])?$_REQUEST['Location']:''?>" multiple>
  <option value="" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['Location']) && $_REQUEST['Location'] == '') 
          echo ' selected="selected"';?></option>
  <option value="ACT" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['Location']) && $_REQUEST['Location'] == 'ACT') 
          echo ' selected="selected"';?>ACT</option>
  <option value="NSW" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['Location']) && $_REQUEST['Location'] == 'NSW') 
          echo ' selected="selected"';?>NSW</option>
   <option value="QLD" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['Location']) && $_REQUEST['Location'] == 'QLD') 
          echo ' selected="selected"';?>QLD</option>
</select>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: What is `getAllRecords()`?

Comment: Try `Location IN (...)` or expand to a series of `x LIKE y` joined by `OR`. You can also crunch them down into a single regular expression for `RLIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

If the Locations are represented one-to-one, you can use `IN` to search, like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE Location IN ('QLD', 'NSW');
```

If the Locations are just part of the string, you can compare with OR in your query, like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE Location LIKE '%QLD%' OR Location LIKE '%NSW%';
```

To represent a solution, based on your own code, I'll try and fit it in using IN and replacing `$_REQUEST` with `$_POST` (because control over your HTTP methods is more secure).

```php
<?php
$condition = '';
if(!empty($_POST['Location')){
    $condition  .=  " AND Location IN ('" . implode("', '", $_POST['Location']) ."')";
}

$userData   =   $db->getAllRecords('candidates','*',$condition,'ORDER BY id ASC');
?>
```

**Please be ware that this is just an example!** Your code is open to SQL injection which you should address ASAP!

Without knowing what abstraction layer `$db` is, I can only urge you to look into "sql injection" and "mysql prepared statements" on your favorite search engine.